# Laravel 4 clean code review of users controller and model, trying to maintain MVC structure

Tags: php, mvc, laravel

I'd like you to review my attempt at creating an authorization class and let me know if there is re-factoring to be done and/or how I can make the code cleaner and abide by the MVC structure.

**UsersController.php**

```
<?php

    class UsersController extends BaseController {

    protected $user;

    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->beforeFilter('csrf', array('on' => 'post'));
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function getRegister() 
    {
        return View::make('admin.register');
    }

    public function postRegister()
    {
        try 
        {
            $this->user->insertUserIntoDatabase(Input::all());
        } 
        catch (ValidationError $e) 
        {
            return Redirect::to('admin/register')
            ->with('message', 'Something went wrong')
            ->withInput()   
            ->withErrors($e->getErrors());
        }

        return Redirect::to('admin/login')
                ->with('message', 'Thank you for creating a new account');
    }

    public function getLogin()
    {
        return View::make('admin.login');
    }

    public function postLogin()
    {
        if (Auth::attempt(array('email' => Input::get('email'), 'password' => Input::get('password') ))){
            return Redirect::to('admin/dashboard')->with('message', 'Thanks for logging in');
        }

        return Redirect::to('admin/login')->with('message', 'Your email/password combo failed.');
    }

    public function getLogout()
    {
        Auth::logout();
        return Redirect::to('admin/login')->with('message', 'You have been logged out.');
    }

    public function getDashboard()
    {
        return View::make('admin/dashboard');
    }   
}
```

**Users.php (Model)**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    /**
    * The database table used by the model.
    *
    * @var string
    */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
    * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
    *
    * @var array
    */
    protected $hidden = array('password');

    protected $fillable = array('firstname', 'lastname', 'email');
    /**
    * Get the unique identifier for the user.
    *
    * @return mixed
    */
    public function getAuthIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }

    /**
    * Get the password for the user.
    *
    * @return string
    */
    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
    * Get the e-mail address where password reminders are sent.
    *
    * @return string
    */
    public function getReminderEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function insertUserIntoDatabase($input)
    {
        $validation = new Services\Validators\Users;

        if ($validation->passes()) {

            $user = new User;
            $user->firstname = Input::get('firstname');
            $user->lastname = Input::get('lastname');
            $user->email = Input::get('email');
            $user->password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));
            $user->save();
        }

        else {
            $this->errors = $validation->errors;
            throw new ValidationError($validation->errors);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't used PHP in the last few years, so just some generic notes:

1. The `$input` parameter of `insertUserIntoDatabase($input)` is unused. I guess you wanted to use the parameter instead of direct `Input::` calls inside the function.
2. You could use a [guard clause](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/01/flattening-arrow-code.html) in `insertUserIntoDatabase` to make the code flatten:

   ```
   public function insertUserIntoDatabase($input)
   {
       $validation = new Services\Validators\Users;

       if (!$validation->passes()) {
           $this->errors = $validation->errors;
           throw new ValidationError($validation->errors);
       }

       $user = new User;
       $user->firstname = Input::get('firstname');
       $user->lastname = Input::get('lastname');
       $user->email = Input::get('email');
       $user->password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));
       $user->save();
   }
   ```
3. The fields in the User class are `protected`. You might want to use `private` instead. See: [Should I always use the private access modifier for class fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5484845/843804); *Item 13* of *Effective Java 2nd Edition*: *Minimize the accessibility of classes and members*.
4. In `postRegister()` you could move the return inside the try block. I guess `Redirect::to` doesn't throw any `ValidationError` exceptions, so the following is the same:

   ```
   public function postRegister()
   {
       try 
       {
           $this->user->insertUserIntoDatabase(Input::all());
           return Redirect::to('admin/login')
               ->with('message', 'Thank you for creating a new account');
       } 
       catch (ValidationError $e) 
       {
           return Redirect::to('admin/register')
           ->with('message', 'Something went wrong')
           ->withInput()   
           ->withErrors($e->getErrors());
       }
   }
   ```
5. ```
   if (Auth::attempt(array('email' => Input::get('email'), 'password' => Input::get('password') ))){
       return Redirect::to('admin/dashboard')->with('message', 'Thanks for logging in');
   }
   ```

   I would create an explanatory local variable for the array for better readability:

   ```
   $credentials = array(
       'email' => Input::get('email'), 
       'password' => Input::get('password') 
   );
   if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
       return Redirect::to('admin/dashboard')->with('message', 'Thanks for logging in');
   }
   ```

   (*Clean Code* by *Robert C. Martin*, *G19: Use Explanatory Variables*;  *Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code by Martin Fowler*, *Introduce Explaining Variable*)

Comment: I think that your guard clause logic might be reversed.  It appears to be saying, "If validation passes, then throw an error".  Should it be, if(!$validation->passes()) ?

Comment: @clone45: Yes, you're right, it should be that. Thanks, I've fixed it.